# jquery hover and line rotate animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

https://jsfiddle.net/eunjin/zasmLkzm/4/

```
$('#menu_bar').hover(function(){
    $('.line1').stop().animate({borderSpacing:45},{
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
    $('.line3').stop().animate({borderSpacing:-45},{
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
}, function(){
    $('.line1').stop().animate({borderSpacing:0},{
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
    $('.line3').stop().animate({borderSpacing:0},{
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
            $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
});
```

i show someone's code and using it but it doesn't rotate on - code
when i type +45, it rotate hover and unhover 
but type -45 it rotate hover but unhover, it doesn't rotate smoothly

sorry to my english i don't use Eng to my mother language

Comment: You can add this css: `.line1 {
    transform-origin: 50% 150% 0;
}`. Once you change the transform origin it will work as you expect. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zasmLkzm/7/).

Comment: my problem is .line3 because .line1 is rotate smoothly but .line3 isn't TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because in the jQuery animate function of the un-hover part the initial value of borderSpacing is 0 and you are going to 0. You can validate this using `console.log` on the step function to print out `now` and `fx`. Don't use `borderSpacing` since it points to a valid CSS property which **SHOULD** not be negative (Source - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp Look at the *Property Values* heading, value *length*.).

Just use a pseudo property like `rotate` which works successfully here -

https://jsfiddle.net/zasmLkzm/10/

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh it because borderSpacing! thank you to answer my question!!

Comment: Happy to help, you can even vote me up if you like :P